# How to pip list with package urls

Tags: python, pip

I want to get a list of installed PIP packages with the URLs to those packages.

I know that there is `pip list` command that lists all the packages installed, but it doesn't show the URL to package home page.

There is also `pip show` command that shows info about a package including its URL, but it only works for one package.

Is there a way to combine both commands to get a full list of packages with their respective home page URLs?

Comment: I would just do a bash for loop or use `xargs`.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

One way to do it is with this shell one-liner:

```
pip list --format=freeze | cut -d= -f1 | xargs pip show | awk '/^Name/{printf $2} /^Home-page/{print ": "$2}'
```

Where we simply reformatted the output of the `pip show` command being executed via `xargs` for all packages returned by `pip list`.

Sample output:

```
appdirs: http://github.com/ActiveState/appdirs
packaging: https://github.com/pypa/packaging
pip: https://pip.pypa.io/
setuptools: https://github.com/pypa/setuptools
six: http://pypi.python.org/pypi/six/
wheel: https://bitbucket.org/pypa/wheel/
```

Answer (score 3):

Here's a Python script that will show each package name along with its home page URL. It's a bit convoluted because pip doesn't have a public API, so you have to use its main entry point and capture stdout.

```
import pip
import sys

if sys.version_info[0] == 2:
    import StringIO
    IO = StringIO.StringIO
else:
    import io
    IO = io.StringIO

def capture_pip_output(args):
    stdout = IO()
    sys.stdout = stdout
    pip.main(args)
    sys.stdout = sys.__stdout__
    return stdout.getvalue().splitlines()

packages = capture_pip_output(['list', '--format', 'freeze'])
packages = [line.split('==', 1) for line in packages]

for package, version in packages:
    info = capture_pip_output(['show', package])
    for line in info:
        if line.startswith('Home-page: '):
            url = line.split(': ', 1)[1]
            break
    print('{package} {url}'.format(package=package, url=url))
```

Comment: Thank you! However, this did not work for me. I'm getting:

    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "/home/mike/.pyenv/versions/2.7.3/lib/python2.7/logging/__init__.py", line 867, in emit write(fs % msg)
    TypeError: unicode argument expected, got 'str'
    Logged from file list.py, line 250

after running `packages = capture_pip_output(['list', '--format', 'freeze'])` in Django shell

Comment: I targeted Python 3. I'll update it so it will work on Python 2 also.